# How do I restart my loop with get_next_post()?

Tags: posts, loop, get-posts

I'm looking for a succinct method of making `get_next_post()`

double back to the beginning once it hits the last post.

Currently, it stops once it hits the final post.

Here are a few lines of code from the codex 

for context that are similar to what I'm using:

```
    <?php $next_post = get_next_post();
    if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>">
            <?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

`get_next_post` doesn't really know what the "beginning" is. `get_next_post` uses `get_adjacent_posts`. If you [look at the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1131), you can see that that function runs its own query to determine the next (or previous) post ***relative to the current post***. It doesn't loop through a list.

To get the "first" post, you will need to run a new query based on whatever parameters that you decide meet the condition of returning the first post. Something like this:

```
while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  the_title();
  $next_post = get_next_post();
  if (empty($next_post)) {
    echo 'empty'; 
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
    );
    $first = new WP_Query($args);
    var_dump($first->post);
  }
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Also, "next" and "previous" are relative to sort order with "next" meaning closest ***newer*** post. In an ordinary default archive Loop, the first post in the list will not have a "next" post. I suspect you actually want to be using `previous_post_link` but that is a guess.

Comment: Thanks @s_ha_dum This isn't quite what I'm looking for but it's close. Using `var_dump($first->post)` helped. Right now, I'm using `<?php echo get_permalink( get_post(1) ); ?>` to get a link to the first post by id. Is there a succinct method of acquiring the first post's ID without using a static number?

Comment: `$first->post->ID` is the post ID, and you can pass `get_permalink` an ID or a post object. You don't need to run `get_post` and don't really have to specify the ID if you pass a post object. Since `$first->post` is a post object, all you need is `get_permalink($first->post))`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I tried `get_permalink( $first->post )` as well as `get_permalink( $first->post->ID )` but to no avail. Only referencing the first post's ID directly, via `get_post(1)` works?

Comment: I don't know why you are seeing what you describe but it should not be that way, and ___isn't___ that way when I test it.